# Replace div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace 1 div with another using `a href` links and jquery. Here is my setup.

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
<div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
</div>
<div id="replacepagelinks">
     <a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>
     <a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this using jquery? I would also like `<a href=#1"></a>` to disappear when it is selected and `<a href="#2"></a>` to appear and vice versa if that is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's very possible, but do you have *any* code you've tried yet?

Comment: Start with CSS to show only the initial content and the initial link. Then on click of the link, hide the visible content, show the other content, hide the active link and show the other link. Done. Try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide the content based on the clicked element, you can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#replacepagelinks a').click(function(){
       $(this).hide().siblings().show()
       var w = this.hash.replace('#', '');
       $('#parent div.child'+w).show().siblings().hide()
   })
})
```

Comment: you could add the CSS for the initial view

Comment: @devnull69 Yes, of course initially some elements should be hidden, I leaved that part for OP.

Comment: @user1736794 Hi, you haven't used DOMReady on jsfiddle, I replaced the href with hash http://jsfiddle.net/9U5w6/ You are welcome.

Comment: One more thing. :) How do i hide child2 and #2 so that initially only child1 and #1 is displayed? @undefined

Comment: Just one more question before i leave you peace :) I have worked out that i would like the two links in two separate classes so i can display them at either side of the page (rather than the same position) Is this possible? Thanks again for your time. Pia @undefined

Comment: @user1736794 sorry, you should post another question for that :).

Comment: I have also run into a big problem haha. Oh dear. I have these div's appearing from a jquery drop down menu. click on 'A' and it displays items starting with 'A'. Inside 'A' child1 div is displayed. Click "next" and this displays child2 as expected. However if i now click on menu item 'B' it displays child2 and not child1 as expected. Is there any way to reset the jquery whenever a new menu item, 'A', 'B', 'C' etc is selected? (should i post this as a new question?) @undefined